# NativeScript Webview - How to see console outputs

Tags: debugging, nativescript

I'm building an app in NativeScript {N} where I'm implementing a webview.

All of this is working fine, but in my webpage, I would like to get some JS debug statements. How can I see the webview console.log output?
Previously I was able to "inspect" it through Safari, but that option is not presented in the "Develop" menu anymore.

Answer (score 2):

If like me you could not figure out how to do this using the webview proivded by nativescript you'll need to install this plugin to get what you need.
https://github.com/shripalsoni04/nativescript-webview-interface
I provides a lot more features more than the stock. Basically, it allows you to emit events to the android from the webview layer. The author provides a good tutorial on this.